# Let $H(x) = \sqrt{(3x + 1)^{12} +3} $Find three functions $f, g,$ and $h$ satisfying $f(g(h(x))) = f \cdot g \cdot h(x) = H(x)$

Tags: calculus

Let $$H(x) = \sqrt{(3x + 1)^{12} +3} $$

a.) Find three functions $f, g,$ and $h$ satisfying $f(g(h(x))) = f \circ g \circ h(x) = H(x)$

Comment: What did you try? You have to see $H$ as a composite of functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are more than one way, but usually look at the expression and go from inside outward, and if we do $h,g,f$ in that order the result will be $f(g(h(x)))$. In your function, if start with $x$ we could first find $h(x)=3x+1,$ then find $g(h(x))=h(x)^{12}+3$ [so $g(x)=x^{12}+3$,] and finally $f(g(x))=\sqrt{g(x)}$ so $f(x)=\sqrt{x}.$

Comment: @rdias -- You're right about your edit, I should have included the compositions better (edit accepted.)

Comment: Okay, but then what happened in g(x) where you took the exponent and applied it to 3x +1? wouldn't it be (3x^12)+12? Or what am i doing wrong when you apply the exponent to h(x)?

Comment: If $g(x)=x^{12}+3$ then to apply to $3x+1$ first put parentheses around that, so $(3x+1),$ and *then* put that in for $x,$ so getting $(3x+1)^{12}+3.$

Answer (score 1):

One trivial answer is $f(x)=x, g(x)=x, h(x)=H(x)$.

Which is why it's important to provide some context to the question.